# Change target ios version when installing new pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Whenever I install a new pod project, and for example I install firebase libraries I always get installed libraries to be targeted for projects 8.0 or and I start changing them manually to be 9.0 or 14.0 because of the warning that I'm Getting.

[image: Warning Errors]

Here it is the Podfile content:

```
 platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'TestProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestProject

        pod 'SDWebImageSwiftUI'
        pod 'lottie-ios'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth'
        pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

How it is possible to update target iOS all at once, so I won't be updating all the libraries one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your `Podfile` and then `pod install`.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end
```

This will update all the Pod targets at once to your desired version.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Podfile, Warren's answer might not be enough to set all targets to the new deployment target. I recommend using this post-install handler:

```
deployment_target = '14.0'

post_install do |installer|
    installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
        project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
            end
        end
        project.build_configurations.each do |bc|
            bc.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
        end
    end
end
```

This addition becomes important when you use options like `install! 'cocoapods', :generate_multiple_pod_projects => true`